# Which graph type it is?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, graph

please check out the image and please let me know which type graph it is?
In swift I want to draw this, so please suggest graph framework to achieve this graph.

[image: Graph Image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It's Scatter with Smooth Lines Graph